# Right Sidebar doesn't want to work with Bootstrap .container class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkb0sk4b/) with a right and a left sidebars.  The bootstrap container class works great with the left side bar with text wrapping and all that.
But the Right Sidebar doesn't work quite right. Text gets tucked underneath it and doesn't wrap correctly.  I also want to hide the sidebars at certain media points as well and want the container to work correctly at that point as well...

Can someone give me some pointers on getting my right sidebar and container to work correctly with each other?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>sidebar test</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
    .sidebar-fixed-left {
      width: 200px;
      position: fixed;
      border-radius: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .sidebar-fixed-left + .container {
      padding-left: 220px;
    }

    .sidebar-fixed-right {
      width: 200px;
      position: fixed;
      border-radius: 0;
      height: 100%;
      right: 0;
    }

    .sidebar-fixed-right + .container {
      padding-left: 220px;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="navbar-inverse sidebar-fixed-left">
</div>
<div class="navbar-inverse sidebar-fixed-right">
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <h2>Left and Rigth sidebars (Fixed)</h2>

   <p>Left and Right sidebars</p>
 </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```